# Working with two different tfs projects (with different logins) in ms vs 2012

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I want to work with two different tfs servers with different accounts in one ms vs 2012. Is it real?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I currently work with four different TFS servers with different accounts in VS2010 and it works fine.  I suggest you try it and see.

Comment: Does it mean you just added the second server to list of tfs servers, input login and password and that's it?

Comment: Yes that's basically it.